# How to import datasets as csv file to power bi using rest api?

Tags: rest, api, import, powerbi

I want to automate the import process in power bi, But I can't find how to publish a csv file as a dataset.
I'm using a C# solution for this.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why you need to publisch as dataset? just import the csv in powerbi..

Comment: @Aldert yes I want to import it, using the API. But I can't do that by 'just' importing the file. I get a 'requestedFileIsEncryptedOrCorrupted' http error.

Comment: So can you open it in excel?

Comment: @Aldert yes. It happens with any csv or xlsx file. If I do it manually through app.powerbi, it goes smoothly even using the same csv file. I don't know what are the changes that must be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Power BI updates, it is now possible to import the dataset without importing the whole report. 
So what I do is that I import the new dataset and I update parameters that I set up for the csv file source (stored in Data lake).

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly import CSV files into a published dataset in Power BI Service. [`AddRowsAPIEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdataset#dataset) property of datasets published from Power BI Desktop is `false`, i.e. this API is disabled. Currently the only way to enable this API is to create a push dataset programatically using the API (or create a [streaming dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming) from the site). In this case you will be able to push rows to it (read the CSV file and push batches of rows, either using C# or some other language, even PowerShell). In this case you will be able to create reports with using this dataset. However there are lots of limitations and you should take care of cleaning up the dataset (to avoid reaching the limit of 5 million rows, but you can't delete "some" of the rows, only to truncate the whole dataset) or to make it [basicFIFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup#defaultretentionpolicy) and [lower the limit to 200k rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/api-automatic-retention-policy-for-real-time-data).

However a better solution will be to automate the import of these CSV files to some database and make the report read the data from there. For example import these files into Azure SQL Database or Data Bricks, and use this as a data source for your report. You can then schedule the refresh of this dataset (in case you use imported) or use Direct Query.

Comment: Yes,unfortunatly that is true. However, I found out that I can create a dataset, then convert my csv to JSON and push that data to the newly created dataset in Power BI.But It doesn't resolve my problem seeing that I have many calculated values.

Comment: You can replicate these calculations as measures (see the definition for [measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup#table) in Table) when creating the dataset, or simply create columns for them and calculate their values in your program, which will push the data to this dataset. But this doesn't solve the rest of the problems that I mentioned, if you are using approach.

Comment: Yes indeed. Okey will give it a try then. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thank you for the answer, but the limitation with the second alternative (database) is that you cannot instantiate the reports automatically via the api. manual manipulations must be done, in order to connect the database to the report as a data source. Can you confirm this to me please ?

Comment: Nope, these reports can be deployed and switched to appropriate databases automatically without any manual steps.

Comment: @zahma You can use [Post Import In group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/postimportingroup) or [Clone Import In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereportingroup) to create new report with [How to automatically change server in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287873/how-to-automatically-change-server-in-connection-string/58288879#58288879) to redirect it to the desired database.