# How to change/update dataset source file?

Tags: dataset, powerbi

I'm searching for a solution to change dataset source data in power bi. I want a scriptable way using C# to update datasets, and make it use another specific local file, using the Power BI rest API. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this, there is indeed a way, and it's by setting up the file source as a parameter in the power query.

All I do after is using the API to Updated this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this! Power BI REST API work with Power BI Service, which is in the cloud, and it will be a challenging task to give it access to files on your local drive!

Your problem (as asked in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431734/how-to-import-datasets-as-csv-file-to-power-bi-using-rest-api/)) is that you are skipping layers from the [recommended data warehouse architecture](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/modern-data-warehouse/) and try to combine them all in Power BI only. Just put these files somewhere in the cloud (Azure Data Lake, Azure SQL Database, OneDrive for Business, etc.) and use them as a datasource for your reports. You can also put them in a database on-premise and use [Power BI Gatawey](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) to connect to it from Power BI Service. See [Get data from Comma Separated Value (.CSV) files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-comma-separated-value-files). This will give you the flexibility to push data the way you want, even to clean up the historical data that you don't need anymore.

If you need to be able to programatically switch the data source for your report, then you can define it with parameters (e.g. `ServerName` and `DatabaseName`) and change their values using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup). See [Power BI Introduction: Working with Parameters in Power BI Desktop —Part 4](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/power-bi-introduction-working-with-parameters-in-power-bi-desktop-part-4/) for more details how to implement connection-specific parameters.

Comment: Thank you for this. But the thing is, I'm working on a project, where I want to automate a BI pipeline. I have a report kind of model that I'm working with, for all other reports. The only changes are the datasources (csv files). So what I am thinking about, is importing the new datasource, cloning the model report and then affect the new datasource to the cloned one. And ofcourse renaming it. Everything has to be scriptable. Nothing manual. That's the challenge. And for now, the only obstacle is the datasource's import.

Comment: Yes, you have difficulties, because you are doing it the hard way. It is way more easier to push data to a "normal" datasource, e.g. a relational database. This way you will be able to change the data source by using connection specific parameters for that and change it programatically, but it's your choice.

Comment: Well, I have my data stored in Data lake storage. I'm trying to use the update datasource API this time, to change the file used in dataset. But again I have some problems, I get  an error "message=Dataset doesn't contain a datasource that matches selector #1".

Comment: View the M code for getting the data. Replace container name or folder with parameter and use the API to change its value, thus to change the data source.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing. Thank you!